# Find perfect finite group whose quotient by center equals the same quotient for two other groups and has both as a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two finite perfect groups such that $G_1 / Z(G_1) \cong G_2 / Z(G_2)$. Then there exists a finite perfect group $G$  and subgroups $Z_1, Z_2 \le Z(G)$ with
$$
 G / Z(G) \cong G_i / Z(G_i) \quad
 \mbox{and} \quad
 G / Z_i \cong G_i, \quad i = 1,2.
$$

I want to construct the group $G$. I tried to start from the direct product $G_1 \times G_2$ and factor out an appropriate normal subgroup, but everything I try does not give the desired properties. And also I have no idea how to incorporate the assumption that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are perfect. So any hints on this exercise?

This exercise is taken from the book *Theory of finite groups* by H. Kurzweil and B. Stellmacher, and appears there on page 36.

Comment: I think the pullback of $G_1$ and $G_2$ should work... I'll try to prove it and get back to you

Comment: The pullback itself might not be perfect, but its commutator subgroup is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an outline argument, not a full solution.

Let $X=  G_1/Z(G_1) \cong G_2/Z(G_2)$ and let $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$ be the associated epimorphisms $\rho_1:G_1 \to X$ and $\rho_2:G_2 \to X$.

Now let $H = \{ (g_1,g_2) \in G_1 \times G_2 \mid \rho_1(g_1) = \rho_2(g_2) \}$ and put $G = [H,H]$. Note that $G$ is perfect by 1.5.3 in the book, and $G$ projects onto both $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: PS: $H$ is called fibre product of $(G_1,\rho_1)$ and $(G_2,\rho_2)$ and is the pullback mentioned in "HallaSurvivor"'s comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more elaborated sketch of [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3419168/269050).

1. Write $\bar G_i=G_i/Z(G_i)$ and let $\theta\colon \bar G_1\to\bar G_2$ be an isomorphism. Consider the following commutative diagram

[image]

2. Define
   $$
     H = \{\phi_1\circ\rho_1=\varphi_2\circ\rho_2\}\leqslant G_1\times G_2.
   $$
3. Observe that
   $$
     H = \{(x_1,x_2)\mid \theta(\bar x_1)=\bar x_2\}.
   $$
4. Note that
   $$
     [(\bar x,\theta(x)),(\bar y,\theta(\bar y))]
           = ([\bar x,\bar y],\theta([\bar x,\bar y])).
   $$
5. Put $Z=Z(G_1\times G_2)$. Then $H/Z$ (the graph of $\theta$) is perfect.
6. $G=H'$ is perfect.
7. $G\cap Z=Z(G)$.
8. The (restriction of the) projections $G\to G_i$ are epi.
9. Define $Z_i=\text{ker}(G\to G_i)$. Then $Z_i\subseteq Z(G)$.